# Scrapy and respect of robots.txt

Tags: scrapy, robots.txt

I discovered yesterday that Scrapy respects the robots.txt file by default (`ROBOTSTXT_OBEY = True`).

If I request an URL with `scrapy shell url`, and if I have a response, does it mean that `url` is not protected by robots.txt?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

According to the docs, it's enabled by default only when you create a project using `scrapy startproject` command, otherwise should be default `False`.

https://docs.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/settings.html#robotstxt-obey
https://docs.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/downloader-middleware.html#topics-dlmw-robots

Answering your question, yes, `scrapy shell` command does respect `robots.txt` configuration defined in `settings.py`. If `ROBOTSTXT_OBEY = True`, trying to use `scrapy shell` command on a protected URL will generate a response `None`.

You can also test it passing robots.txt settings via command line:

```
scrapy shell https://www.netflix.com --set="ROBOTSTXT_OBEY=True"
```