# Puppeteer code to respect robots.txt file

Tags: javascript, puppeteer

This seems to be possible in Scrapy [Scrapy and respect of robots.txt](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55297976/scrapy-and-respect-of-robots-txt) but is there a simple way to do this in Puppeteer?

I haven't found an easy way to build in "respect the Robots" into Puppeteer commands.

Answer (score 2):

I don't believe puppeteer has anything built in but you can use puppeteer to access `robots.txt` and then use any of a number of `npm` modules to parse `robots.txt` to see if you're allowed to get any particular URL. For example, here's how you might use [robots-txt-parser](https://www.npmjs.com/package/robots-txt-parser):

```
const robotsParser = require('robots-txt-parser')
const robots = robotsParser()

// Now inside an async function
// (or not if using a version of Node.js that supports top-level await)

await robots.useRobotsFor('https://example.com/')
if (await robots.canCrawl(urlToVisit)) {
  // Do stuff with puppeteer here to visit the URL
} else {
  // Inform the user that sadly crawling that URL is forbidden
}
```